# Spring injection without getBean and without annotation

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I'm coding my first Spring application from scratch.

I Know the way to inject the dependencies with the ApplicationContext -> getBean and with the annotation @autowired (and others) but I'm working on existing Spring project where I do not need getBean neither annotations.

How does it work?

Has anyone a clue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest you to read something about spring [Spring Framework Reference Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/) before start to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with constructor injection also.

```
public class MyBean
{
   private MyOtherBean myOtherBean;

   public MyBean(MyOtherBean myOtherBean)
   {
      this.myOtherBean = myOtherBean;
   }
}

//your spring config xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<!-- Definition of your bean -->
<bean id="myBean" class="com.yourpackage.MyBean">
  <constructor-arg ref="myOtherBean"/>
</bean>

<bean id="myOtherBean" class="com.yourpackage.MyOtherBean"/>

</beans>
```

Comment: It seems to be what I've done. By property and not by constructor. But it doesn't work... I forgot to say that it is in a servlet application. I try to use my service in the DoGet() method from the servlet...

Comment: so does this solve it for you ? otherwise please elaborate on your question further.

Answer (score 0):

Most likly XML-based bean-definition.
Look for XML in your classpath that define beans.

And read the docu. XML-config is very well documented.

PS:
Do not use ApplicationContext.getBean(...) when ever possible...

Comment: Yes, I tried with the XML configuration but it doesn't work... I forgot to say that it is in a servlet application. I try to use my service in the DoGet() method from the servlet...